# Sencha ExtJs Grid refresh after saving store

Tags: extjs

I have an ExtJS grid with a toolbar button to save the date. The save works and the data is stored. But the grid is not refreshed. How do I reload the grid data after the save?

```
Ext.define('MyLodge.view.content.MemberGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.membergrid',



initComponent: function(){

    var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing');

    var store = Ext.create('MyLodge.store.Members');

    Ext.apply(this, {
        height: this.height,
        plugins: [rowEditing],
        store: store,
        stripeRows: true,
        columnLines: true,
        columns: [{
            id       :'id',
            text: 'ID',
            width: 40,
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },{
            text   : 'Name',
            flex: 1,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'name',
            field: {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        },{
            text   : 'E-Mail',
            width    : 150,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'email',
            field: {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        },{
            text   : 'Href',
            width    : 200,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'href',
            field: {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        }],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                text: 'Add',
                iconCls: 'icon-add',
                handler: function(){
                    // empty record
                    store.insert(0, new MyLodge.model.Member());
                    rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Delete',
                iconCls: 'icon-delete',
                handler: function(){
                    var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
                    if (selection) {
                        store.remove(selection);
                    }
                }
            },'-',{
                text: 'Save',
                iconCls: 'icon-save',
                handler: function(){
                    store.sync();

                }
            }]
        }]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load store in callback of sync

```
store.sync({

        success: function( response ) { 
                 store.load();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to call `store.reload()` in a callback from `store.save()` (what is `store.save()` anyway? it is not part of `Ext.data.Store` interface)